# Find and Replace with Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a document that was converted from PDF to HTML for use on a company website to be referenced and indexed for search. I'm attempting to format the converted document to meet my needs and in doing so I am attempting to clean up some of the junk that was pulled over from when it was a PDF such as page numbers, headers, and footers. luckily all of these lines that need to be removed are in blocks of 4 lines unfortunately they are not exactly the same therefore cannot be removed with a simple literal replace. The lines contain numbers which are incremental as they correlate with the pages. How can I remove the following example from my html file.

```
Title<br>
10<br>
<hr>
<A name=11></a>Footer<br>
```

I've tried many different regular expression attempts but as my skill in that area is limited I can't find the proper syntax. I'm sure i'm missing something fairly easy as it would seem all I need is a wildcard replace for the two numbers in the code and the rest is literal.

any help is apprciated

Comment: An other html could help to manage which part is never changing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search & replace of npp is quite odd. I can't find newline charactes with regular expression, although the documentation says:

> As of v4.9 the Simple find/replace (control+h) has changed, allowing the use of \r \n and \t in regex mode and the extended mode.

I updated to the last version, but it just doesn't work. Using the extended mode allows me to find newlines, but I can't specify wildcards.

However, you can use the **macros** to overcome this problems.

- prepare a search that will find a unique passage (like `Title<br>\r\n`, here you can use the extended mode)
- start recording a macro
- press F3 to use your search
- mark the four lines and delete them
- stop recording the macro ... done!

Just replay it and it deletes what you wanted to delete.

Comment: Thanks alot this was a easy fix for my issue. I was definitely over thinking it the macro was much easier for such a simple removal scenario

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your request correctly this pattern matches your string:

```
Title<br>( ?)\n([0-9]+)<br>( ?)\n<hr>( ?)\n<A name=([0-9]+)></a>Footer<br>
```

I use [the Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) to try out complicated regex patterns.  Other utilities are available.

**edit**

As I do not use Notepad++ I cannot be sure that this pattern will work for you.  Apologies if that transpires to be the case.  (I'm a TextPad man myself, and it does work with that tool).

Comment: notepad++ has unfortunately a bad regex parser - it does not recognize `\n` - at least for me, version 5.6.8

Comment: Notepad++ won't recognize `\n` between lines of text/code if your files' line endings are `\r\n`. I've not had trouble myself with `\n` on LF-terminated-line files.